# How is knowing about the symmetry of a crystal useful

Tags: crystal-structure

I am studying the space groups and know that we use them to talk about crystal symmetry, I would like to know what material properties may be produced or predicted from knowing the symmetry or lack thereof in a crystal system of a material?

Comment: How is this primarily opinion based? He's asking for examples, not opinions.

Comment: I concur, this post should be edited to be more semantically poignant, but as someone in MSE I find no cause to believe that proper answers to this question will be based largely on opinion.

Comment: Thirded. Symmetry is one of the fundamental tools in physics and chemistry, many specific examples can be provided. And I have to say I don't really see how rewording will markedly improve "I would like to know what material properties may be produced or predicted from knowing the symmetry of lack thereof in a crystal system of a material?"

Comment: Thank you, to be fair my original question didn't specifically ask for examples. Is there a way to get an answer on this?

Comment: @chilliBeanDream The question currently sits with three re-open votes. Once it reaches five, the question will be unlocked for answering.

Comment: I think you may have better luck in Physics SE. Nevertheless, let me chip in. The periodicity of the crystal (lattice)  influences the form of its wavefunction. This is due to Bloch's theorem. This doesn't mean that the wavefunction is completely determined just by its periodicity. Other things such as the types of atoms, bonds, surfaces, defects, etc influence the wavefunction. Nevertheless, many properties (e.g bandstructure) are dependent on the wavefunction. Ergo they are influenced by the symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties that are *directly* dependant on crystal symmetry are

- birefringence
- piezoelectricity
- (obviously) x-ray and electron diffraction pattern
- pyroelectricity
- nonlinear optical properties
- ...